# How to center tabularx table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I want to horizontally center a table that is generated with tabularx. But the tabularx table has an offset to the right that I am not able to remove:

```
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{}{@{}X|X|X@{}}\hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{This table is generated with tabularx. This table is generated with tabularx. This table is generated with tabularx. This table is generated with tabularx. This table is generated with tabularx. This table is generated with tabularx. }
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This table is generated with tabular. This table is generated with tabular. This table is generated with tabular. This table is generated with tabular. This table is generated with tabular. This table is generated with tabular.}
\end{table}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of rendered tables comparing tabularx and tabular.]

How can I horizontally center the table in tabularx?

Comment: Unfortunately you're using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) incorrectly. You need to specify a width as the second argument - something you've left blank. Even so, in its current form, you don't need a `tabularx` as it suffices to use all "natural width" columns like `r`, `c` and `l` like in your use with `tabular`.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this if I had a table that required tabularx?

Comment: Specify a width in the second argument of `tabularx`, as in `\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{<col spec>}`, where `<col spec>` has to have at least one `X`-column.

Comment: If a code results in an error (`! Missing number, treated as zero.`  in your case) don't even look at the 'output' but instead try to fix the error.

Comment: never ignore tex error messages, tex does not attempt to make usable pdf output after an error.

Comment: As is, your code in a standard article document should produce the `Missing number, treated as zero.`  fatal error, with no PDF output, not the image that you posted!  The problem *in the code*, as already commented, is the `{}` after `\begin{tabularx}` that should have some absolute length as `7cm` or a relative length as   `.5\linewidth`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Werner Upvoted! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) requires you to specify a width of the resulting table in order for it to calculate the widths of `X`-columns. So, use it like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{10em}{ @{} X | X | X @{} }
    \hline
    a & b & c \\
    \hline
    d & e & f \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{This table is generated with \texttt{tabularx}.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[t]
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
    \hline
    a & b & c \\
    \hline
    d & e & f \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This table is generated with \texttt{tabular}.}
\end{table}

Some regular text.

\end{document}
```